# Fresh Ubuntu Install, Purple then black screen. Shift/Space/Esc won't post GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, nvidia

So I have two SSD, one with my windows 10 install and the other I just use for Steam and other files. I shrinked the partition for the second SSD to make room for a Ubuntu install. Then I booted from a Live USB and ran it with "nomodeset" since even the live USB boot was giving me a black screen. Installed Ubuntu to he second SSD with a 2gb swap partition. Installed fine, did the internet options where it grabbed updates and 3rd party stuff as well. Then when I go to boot up Ubuntu I get a purple blank screen then a black screen. I've read that it is probably a problem with my video card and that I need to take steps within the GRUB menu to get around this so I can install drivers for my video card. But, not matter what I do I cannot get GRUB to post. ESC, SPACE, SHIFT, holding them down, holding them down and releasing, spamming them. None of it does anything. I am at a loss as to what do next. I used the latest LTS .iso. Remade the live USB just incase something was messed up. I have a GEFORCE GTX 970 card if that info is helpful at all. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never found out what was wrong. Swapped to Ubuntu 15 install, everything running fine.